# How to create a generic extension method for including Entity Framework Core nested collection properties taking into account soft deleted ones?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, extension-methods

I have all entities being inherited from `BaseEntity` class which contains an `IsDeleted` property. Now when including nested collections, I need to specify explicitly

```
Where(e => !e.IsDeleted)
```

in `Include` clause:

```
_dbContext.Posts
          .Include(p => p.Comments.Where(c => !c.IsDeleted))
```

How can I create an `IncludeNotDeleted` extension method which could be used like this:

```
_dbContext.Posts.IncludeNotDeleted(p => p.Comments)
```

Please note, that I want this method to work exactly as `Include` and not cause additional database queries or in memory processing.

Comment: Maybe is just enough to define [Global Query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)? Otherwise third party extensions like `LINQKit` are needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, query filter handles my use case, but also would be interesting to see some possible extension method implementation playing with dynamic expressions I assume

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this with EF Core, so there may be some type issues (e.g. where I assume `Comments` is `ICollection<T>`) but here is my attempt to convert the `p => p.Comments` passed in to `p => p.Comments.Where(c => !c.IsDeleted))`:

```
public static class IQueryableExt {
    public static IQueryable<T> IncludeNotDeleted<T, TProp>(this IQueryable<T> q, Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TProp>>> pathExpr)
        where T : class {
        // (T p)
        var pathParm = pathExpr.Parameters[0];
        // p.{property}
        var pathBodyExpr = pathExpr.Body;
        // (TProp prop)
        var filterParm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProp), "prop");
        // !prop.IsDeleted
        var filterBody = Expression.Not(Expression.Property(filterParm, "IsDeleted"));
        // (TProp prop) => !prop.IsDeleted
        var filteredPathExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TProp, bool>>(filterBody, filterParm);
        // p.{property}.Where(prop => !prop.IsDeleted)
        var newBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Where", new[] { typeof(TProp) }, pathBodyExpr, filteredPathExpr);
        // (T p) => p.{property}.Where(prop => !prop.IsDeleted)
        var newPathExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProp>>>(newBody, pathParm);

        return q.Include(newPathExpr);
    }
}
```